# Problema con stored procedures en oracle y con .net

Tags: c#, oracle, web, api, plsql

Tengo una problema que no me deja avanzar en mi trabajo, espero me puedan ayudar.

Estoy haciendo una Web API que se conecta a una base de datos en Oracle, es un simple CRUD, ya hice los Stored Procedures y todo, ya los probé desde Oracle y funcionan a la perfección.

El problema es que después de haber insertado un registro con la Web API después ya no funciona jeje, cuando voy depurando paso a paso se queda colgado en `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` y ya de ahí no pasa, está muy raro y me estresa mucho porque no tengo ni idea de que sea, no tengo el código porque no lo puedo sacar de la computadora de mi trabajo pero tengo un ejemplo que utilizo, para hacer la conexión utilizo `Oracle.DataAccess`.

```
OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connString);
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("sp_ejemploarray", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "cadena", 
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, Value = arrayString });
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "ok", OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });

 connection.Open();
 command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Aquí se queda colgado :(
```

Y el Stored es un simple `insert into table(values) values(params);`.

¿Saben si hay algún problema de compatibilidad o algo? No me muestra ningún mensaje o algo. **Un punto importante**: la base de datos está hecha en Oracle, la Web API con C# y para llamarla uso una página con un AJAX que llama a la API y le envía los parámetros post, estos llegan bien, tengo tres capas y por las dos primeras pasan bien hasta llegar a la capa de datos que es cuando se queda colgada la api. Gracias de antemano, ¡saludos!

Comment: la libreria que usas Oracle.DataAccess la referencia usando nuget? o quizas instalaste el ODAC y la tomas de alli, digo no es una libreria que viene con .net, no?

Comment: estas seguro que el problema es el ExecuteNonQuery(), no sera el Open(), que pasa si llevas el connection.Open(); justo debajo de la linea OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connString); para ver sino se queda congelado en ese punto, porque el que no responda pareciera un problema de conexion a la db y esta esperando el timeout

Comment: Monitorea que la tabla a la que estas accediendo no este bloqueada, una manera simple de hacer esto es con un "select". Verifica que desde otro lugar del codigo no estes accediendo a la misma tabla y por este motivo la estes bloqueando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré el error: me faltaba poner `COMMIT;` después del `INSERT`, por eso se quedaba *colgado*. Después de que lo puse ya no tuve ningún problema.

La librería `Oracle.DataAccess` la descargué del `nuguet`, el `command.Open();` está bien, porque cuando hay algún error te lo muestra al ejecutar paso a paso y, en este caso, no había error, incluso pasaba esa línea rápido, y a la tabla sí le podía hacer `SELECT` sin problema alguno.

Estoy teniendo algunos problemas con las diferencias entre SQL Server y Oracle; es mi primera vez usando Oracle y por eso me falla todavía, pero como dicen, la práctica hace al maestro jeje, saludos y ¡muchas gracias por sus respuestas!

Comment: Puedes marcar tu propia respuesta como aceptada, ya que lograste resolver tu problema. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias, ya iré entendiendo mejor el foro, saludos.